# "as." in names of functions for conversion between data types in R

Tags: r

`as.matrix` will convert a data frame to a matrix. `as.data.frame` will do the opposite conversion.

`ts` will convert a vector, matrix or data frame to a time series object.

So I wonder why `as.` appear in some functions' names, and not in the others? Thanks!

Comment: btw `as.ts` is available too, taking as input "an arbitrary R object"

Comment: what differences between `as.ts` and `ts` then? Is it same as the difference between `matrix` and `as.matrix`? @LucaBraglia

Comment: Sometimes you don't need to create a new data frame, list, etc, because you simply need to pass that data to another function that only accepts a specific class argument.

Answer (score 3):

Following Tim's comment request...

Generally speaking

- `matrix` and `ts` (like other function with `class-like-name`) are
  used when you **create** an object from scratch (eg a `data.frame`
  from a set of vector, a `matrix` from a vector specifying dims).
- `as.matrix` and `as.ts` (like other function like `as.classname`) are
  used to **coerce** an object of a given class to `classname`.

`matrix` and `as.matrix` fits the general rule quite well.

`matrix` is tipically efficient in creating an object from
scratch. You can see that after a few manipulation it call low
level code (via `.Internal`) to provide the correct data
structure.

```
> matrix
function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)
{
    if (is.object(data) || !is.atomic(data))
        data <- as.vector(data)
    .Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames, missing(nrow), missing(ncol)))
}
```

`as.*` function aim (eg `as.matrix`'s one) is totally different because they have to cope
with different/complex data structures, all to be coerced to that considered.
Therefore are somewhat *more high-level* function (pure R mainly)

```
> as.matrix
function (x, ...)
UseMethod("as.matrix")
<bytecode: 0x3a5a2f0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

which objects can be converted to matrix?

```
> methods(as.matrix)
[1] as.matrix.data.frame as.matrix.default
[3] as.matrix.dist*      as.matrix.ftable*
[5] as.matrix.noquote    as.matrix.POSIXlt
[7] as.matrix.raster*

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

try from the console

```
as.matrix.data.frame
as.matrix.ftable
getAnywhere(as.matrix.ftable)
```

HTH :)

Answer (score 2):

Naming a function `as.new_class_name` is part of the S3 function dispatch mechanism. If you want to define a new class and a function to provide coercion to that class, then you make an `as.new_class_name` function and register it using `setClass`. see the examples at:

```
 ?setAs
 ?setClass
```

The interpreter will then be able to properly dispatch to `as.new_class_name` (assuming you have defined it) when it encounters such a call.